RDKit SetScale method for drawing
I am trying to figure out thisn old SO question RDKit SetScale method for drawing:
I can have this code running (from comment below the original SO question : There is a C++ example of using the SetScale function in the rdkit tests: here, This will not be much different to the python API, so you should be able to translate it. If you could add more context to your question and what you have tried so far it will be easier to answer) and get an image, but still dont understand how SetScale works, especiaaly the minv and maxv paramters in:
drawer.SetScale(50, 50, minv, maxv)

here the code:
import rdkit
print('\n-------------------------------')
print('\n rdkit Version : ', rdkit.__version__)
print('\n-------------------------------')

from rdkit import Chem

from rdkit.Chem import Draw

from rdkit.Geometry.rdGeometry import Point2D

from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO


mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles("CCO")
mol = Chem.AddHs(mol)

# drawer = Draw.MolDraw2DSVG(200, 400, 200, 200)

drawer = Draw.MolDraw2DCairo(200, 400, 200, 200)

minv = Point2D(1000, 1000)

maxv = Point2D(-1000, -1000)

drawer.SetScale(10, 10, minv, maxv)

drawer.DrawMolecule(mol)

drawer.SetOffset(0, 200)

drawer.DrawMolecule(mol)

drawer.FinishDrawing()

print('drawer.GetDrawingText() : ', drawer.GetDrawingText() , type(drawer.GetDrawingText()))

bio = BytesIO(drawer.GetDrawingText())

img = Image.open(bio)

img.save('test.png')

img.show()

output image:

